# IIS on Windows 7: 400 bad request when requesting XML files

Tags: xml, iis, windows-7

I have a website running under IIS on Windows 7.
Everytime the webpage requests an XML file I receive a 400 Bad Request (diagnosed through firebug).  If I request the XML file directly by typing it into my browser it works.

This not only happens for `.xml` file extensions but `.xsl` too; both of which contain XML data.

Comment: can you provide more details of how you make your request?

Comment: I'm using Firefox to debug it, can I not use that? The request is made using Javascript. It has worked with every other browser / IIS combination I've ever tested it on so I know its a configuration error with this PC only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.

When requesting the XML files I was adding the `If-Modified-Since` header which is in the HTTP spec but IIS on Windows 7 seems to return `400 Bad Request` when this is added.  Simply removing this header from the request fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is your xml file static or dynamically generated?

If static then check the following:

Your (successful) browser request would be using a GET request. Is your webpage request using POST? If so, POST may not be an accepted verb for a static xml file.

Check the IIS configuration settings for .xml suffix files.

Comment: Static files, using GET.  It also occurs on .XSL files not just .XML files

Comment: OK - try and change your webpage request (jQuery?) to use a GET rather than a POST.