# IIS7's custom redirection doesn't pass If-Modified-Since header. Bug?

Tags: c#, iis-7, url-rewriting, request-headers

We're using the following technique to catch all non-existing URLs and provide our own resulting page:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="Foo" path="foo.aspx" verb="*" type="Foo.UrlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
</handlers>

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <remove statusCode="405"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/foo.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="405" path="/foo.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

However, when I check which request headers are being passed to the `UrlHandler`, I see all but one: the If-Modified-Since header doesn't get passed. I see all the others though (Cache-Control, Accept, etc).

Had any experience with this? It's kind of related to this question:

[Posting forms to a 404 + HttpHandler in IIS7: why has all POST data gone missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102846/posting-forms-to-a-404-httphandler-in-iis7-why-has-all-post-data-gone-missing)

**Update**: I'm not alone - http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_asp_net/3935439.htm

Comment: I recently had a similar problem where it would return `400 Bad Request` if I used `If-Modified-Since` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725729/iis-on-windows-7-400-bad-request-when-requesting-xml-files

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to check modified dates on a 404 response? The link provided describes using 404 responses as a way to handle CMS content management, which seems incredibly backwards to me. What's the scenario you're trying to support?

Comment: I'd like all URLs, regardless the extension, to pass through my code and give me a chance to handle it. Static files ought to be served as-is. I fixed it using .NET MVC, though just for the URLrouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. In case anyone has the same problem:

I changed the project to a .NET MVC (2, but 1-3 should all do fine). Made a single route to catch-all:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute("All", "{*url}", new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });
}
```

Then added a single CatchAll controller to do exactly as my HttpHandler once did.